# How to give a number a variable that is decided when the user write a number in a form?

Tags: php, forms, variables

So I want to change the -new 1 into -new $var and give this $var to the input(getal) so that when i type 5 in the form, i want my jar to be shown 5 times when i press submit.

```
<input type="text" id="getal" value="" name="getal"><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show">

</form>

</body>
</html>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 exec('java -jar "test.jar" -new 1', $response);
 print nl2br(print_r($response, true));
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `dot` and combine string with variable. For example:

```
$var = "yourname";
echo "hello " . $var . ", how are you?;
// prints "hello yourname, how are you?"
```

In your case, you can use this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $var1 = $_POST['var1'];
  $var2 = $_POST['var2'];
  $getal = $_POST['getal'];
  exec('java -jar "test.jar" -db ' . $var1 . ' -h ' . $var2 . ' -new ' . $getal, $response);
  print nl2br(print_r($response, true));
}
```

Your form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="" name="var1">
  <input type="text" value="" name="var2">

  <input type="text" id="getal" value="" name="getal">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show">
</form>
```

Comment: I really thank you for ur time to write an answer but it didnt work.

Comment: OHHH nevermind! I forgot to write " $var = $_POST['getal'];". thank you sir!

Comment: Hey 1 more question,

Comment: What if i had this : exec('java -jar "test.jar" -db test.db.bvba.be -h 10.222.222.22 -new ' . $getal, $response);  I tried to also make a var with test.db.bvba.be and 10.222.222.22 the same way you told me but it doesnt work for them, any advice/help?